# How do I operate the m.withAttr tutorials code?

Tags: mithril.js

**A contrived example of bi-directional data binding**

```
var user = {
    model: function(name) {
        this.name = m.prop(name);
    },
    controller: function() {
        return {user: new user.model("John Doe")};
    },
    view: function(controller) {
        m.render("body", [
            m("input", {onchange: m.withAttr("value", controller.user.name), value: controller.user.name()})
        ]);
    }
};
```

https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.withAttr.html

---

I tried the above code does not work nothing.

It was the first to try to append the following.

```
m.mount(document.body, user);
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n

---

Then I tried to append the following.

```
var users = m.prop([]);
var error = m.prop("");
m.request({method: "GET", url: "/users/index.php"})
        .then(users, error);
```

▼/users/index.php

```
<?php
echo '[{name: "John"}, {name: "Mary"}]';
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n

---

How do I operate the m.withAttr tutorials code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is difficult to operate because it's contrived, it's not meant to be working out-of-the-box. Here's a slightly modified, working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/ciscoheat/8dwenn02/2/

```
var user = {
    model: function(name) {
        this.name = m.prop(name);
    },
    controller: function() {
        return {user: new user.model("John Doe")};
    },
    view: function(controller) {
        return [
            m("input", {
                oninput: m.withAttr("value", controller.user.name),
                value: controller.user.name()
            }),
            m("h1", controller.user.name())
        ];
    }
};

m.mount(document.body, user);
```

**Changes made:**

1. `m.mount` injects html *inside* the element specified as first parameter, so rendering a `body` element in `view` will make a body inside a body.
2. Changed the input field event to `oninput` for instant feedback, and added a `h1` to display the model, so you can see it changing when the input field changes.

### Using m.request

Another example how to make an ajax request that displays the retrieved data, as per your modifications:

http://jsfiddle.net/ciscoheat/3senfh9c/

```
var userList = {
    controller: function() {
        var users = m.prop([]); 
        var error = m.prop("");

        m.request({
            method: "GET", 
            url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
        }).then(users, error);

        return { users: users, error: error };
    },
    view: function(controller) {
        return [
            controller.users().map(function(u) {
                return m("div", u.name)
            }),
            controller.error() ? m(".error", {style: "color:red"}, "Error: " +  controller.error()) : null
        ];
    }
};

m.mount(document.body, userList);
```

The **Unexpected token n** error can happen if the requested url doesn't return valid JSON, so you need to fix the JSON data in `/users/index.php` to make it work with your own code. There are no quotes around the `name` field.

Comment: It worked as expected. Thank you for a detailed description!

Answer (score 1):

[Try returning `m('body', [...])` from your controller.](http://jsfiddle.net/v3oard6f/1/)

```
view: function (ctrl) {
    return m("body", [
        ...
    ]);
}
```

`render` should not be used inside of Mithril components (`render` is only used to mount Mithril components on existing DOM nodes).